# Notations concerning polynomials over and extensions of rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, notation, roots

I find it hard to keep overview over the notations for sets of polynomials, evaluations of polynomials, and [extensions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_extension) of rings and so on.

Let $R$ be a ring, and $E/R$ an extension of $R$.

Occasionally one finds definitions like this

$$\boxed{R(\alpha) = \{ a_0 + a_1\alpha\ |\ a_i \in R\}}$$

for a specific number $\alpha \in E/R$ , i.e. $R(\alpha) \subseteq E/R$ is another set of numbers, for example in Lemmermeyer's [Quadratische Zahlkörper](https://www.springer.com/de/book/9783662538210):

[image]

On the other side, the ring of polynomials over $R$ is defined by

$$\boxed{R[X] = \{a_0 + a_1X + \dots + a_nX^n\ |\ n \in \mathbb{N}, a_i\in R\}}$$

with a unspecific variable $X$, i.e. $R[X]$ is a set of "open" algebraic expressions.

With

$$\boxed{R^k[X] = \{a_0 + a_1X + \dots + a_kX^k\ |\  a_i\in R\}}$$

one can write

$$\boxed{R[X] = \bigcup_{k=0}^{k< \infty}R^k[X]}$$

Next to $R[X]$ we find the definition of

$$\boxed{R(X) = \Big\{ \frac{P}{Q}\ |\ P, Q \in R[X], Q \neq 0\Big\}}$$

If $R[X]$ is a set of algebraic expressions (with a variable $X$), $R[\alpha] = R[X \rightarrow \alpha]$ is a set of numbers by setting the variable $X$ to the numerical value $\alpha$:

$$\boxed{R[\alpha] = \{a_0 + a_1\alpha^1 + \dots + a_n\alpha^n\ |\ n \in \mathbb{N}, a_i\in R\}}$$

or

$$\boxed{R[\alpha] = \{P(X\rightarrow \alpha)\ |\ P \in R[X]\}}$$

Accordingly:

$$\boxed{R[\alpha] = \bigcup_{k=0}^{k < \infty}R^k[\alpha]}$$

Occasionally:

$$\boxed{R[\alpha] = R^1[\alpha] = R(\alpha)}$$

e.g. for $R = \mathbb{Q}$, $\alpha=\sqrt{2}$ (more generally: $\alpha = \sqrt{d}$, $d$ square-free). <sub>[Thanks to user Servaes.]</sub>

Things would be easier if a consistent notation was used, especially $R^1[\alpha]$ instead of $R(\alpha)$ for the set $\{ a_0 + a_1\alpha\ |\ a_i \in R\}$.

Finally, there is one notation I'm desperately missing: for the minimal extension of a ring $R$ that contains all roots of a polynomial $P(X) \in R[X]$:

$$\boxed{R\langle P\rangle = R[\rho_1]\dots[\rho_k]}$$

for the roots $\rho_i$ of $P(X)$, i.e. $P(\rho_i) = 0$. It's essential (or isn't it?) that

$$\boxed{R[\rho_1]\dots[\rho_k] = R[\pi(\rho_1)]\dots[\pi(\rho_k)]}$$

for any permutation $\pi$ of the roots.

Note that $\mathbb{Z}[\frac{1}{2}]$ is an **infinite-dimensional** vector space over $\mathbb{Z}$ (with base $\{1,\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{8},\dots\}$, while $\mathbb{Z}^1[\sqrt{2}] = \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}] $ is a **two-dimensional** one (with base $\{1,\sqrt{2}\}$) - like $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-1}]$ (with base $\{1,i\}$)!

My question is:

> Are there attempts to unify (= optimize) notation in the context of polynomials,
>   evaluation of polynomials, and extensions of rings and fields that minimize
>   confusion (that occasionally arises with established notation)?

Comment: Note that in the case of a squarefree integer $m$ we have
$$\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{m})=\Bbb{Q}[\sqrt{m}]=\Bbb{Q}^1[\sqrt{m}],$$
hence the notation is entirely consistent. As for the minimal extension containing all roots of a polynomial; I've often seen the notation $\Omega_P^R$ used in the context of field theory, but I guess it works just as well for rings.

Comment: "You've seen": just occasionally? Isn't there an established notation?

Comment: ...do you have a question?

Comment: @EricWofsey: Very good question! I forgot about it.

Comment: Each math author is welcome to define a notation (providing a definition) that "optimizes" the discussion of a topic.  At the beginning of your post you have "$R(\alpha) = \{a_0 + a_1 \alpha \mid a_0,a_1 \in R \}$" which already involves some abbreviation that might cause confusion.   This construction of *a ring* $R(\alpha)$ depends on some overring $S$ of $R$ where the arithmetic $a_0 + a_1 \alpha$ is already defined, and crucially, on $\alpha$ satisfying a monic quadratic polynomial over $R$.   So it's helpful if those points are clear to a Reader, not so helpful otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

The definitions of $R(\alpha)$, $R[\alpha]$ an $R^k[\alpha]$ you give are all unambiguous and in widespread use (though $R_k[\alpha]$ is also used for the latter), so there is no ambiguity or possibility of confusion to be prevented. Note that in your particular case of a squarefree integer $m$ we have
$$\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{m})=\Bbb{Q}[\sqrt{m}]=\Bbb{Q}^1[\sqrt{m}],$$
hence the notation is entirely consistent.

As for the minimal extension containing all roots of a polynomial; I've often seen the notation $\Omega_P^R$ used in the context of field theory, but I guess it works just as well for rings.

Comment: I totally disagree that $R^k[\alpha]$ (or $R_k[\alpha]$) are "unambiguous and in widespread use".  I have pretty much never seen either of those notations.  And lacking context that indicates otherwise, I would assume they instead mean $S[\alpha]$ where $S=R^k$ or $S=R_k$ is a different ring.